# How to render table and math in Rmarkdown when called from Shiny App

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, markdown

I have a Rmarkdown file (`info.rmd`) that looks like this:

````
---
title: "Information"
theme: yeti
date: "4/1/2017"
output: html_document
---


## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.


```{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
library(knitr)
kable(mtcars[1:5, ], caption = "A knitr kable.")
```

## Formulation

Here is where we formulate
$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
````

And the ShinyApp that calls Rmarkdown like this:

**server.R**

contains this

```
  output$markdown <- renderUI({
    HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('info.rmd', quiet = TRUE), fragment.only=TRUE))
  })
```

**ui.R**

contains this:

```
 fluidPage(uiOutput('markdown'))
```

But how come the table and math generated looks like this?

[image]

What's the right way to do it?

---

When run independently outside Shiny the `info.rmd` produces the table properly:

[image]

---

I tried this in `ui.R`

```
 includeHTML("info.html")
```

Which shows the file html correctly, but prevent the plotting
and reactivity in other `tabPanel()` to work.

---

**Update**

Here is the new result after @Nice solution:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps different CSS? Browse through the generated HTML code...

Answer (score 5):

If you use `fragment.only`, the CSS and JS is not included and the table/equation is not styled.

One easy way to do this is to include the full HTML, with the header, in an iframe so it does not interfere with the rest of your app.

```
output$markdown <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src='info.html',width="100%",frameBorder="0",height="1000px")
  })
```

The `info.html` file needs to be in the `www` folder of your app. You can adjust the width and height of the iframe by changing the parameters in the `tags$iframe`.

You can change the width of the main container in the iframe using CSS. If you add this to your info.rmd file:

````
```{r results="asis",echo = FALSE}
cat("
<style>
.main-container.container-fluid {
   max-width: 100%;
   padding-left:0px;
}
</style>
")
```
````

Comment: Thanks. But the inserted html is shrinked. How can I span it over the full navbar length. See my update.

Comment: I edit, the main container in the rmd file has a max-width so it doesn't span the full page, you can change it with css. You'll need to knit it again and put the new info.html in the www folder.

Comment: Thanks I tried. It improve. But still indented to certain degree. We'd like the text "Description" to be aligned with the Navbars `Exp1`.

Comment: You can also remove the `padding-left` from the .container-fluid in the iframe but after that will put the text to the left of the container holding. If there is still space it's probably due to the padding of other divs in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the shiny server part with the following should help:

```
output$markdown <- renderUI({
    markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('info.rmd', quiet = TRUE), fragment.only=TRUE)
    withMathJax(includeHTML("info.html"))
  })
```

Alternatively you can also do the following:

```
output$markdown <- renderUI({
    markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('info.rmd', quiet = TRUE), fragment.only=TRUE)
    withMathJax(includeMarkdown("info.md"))
  })
```

Comment: How about the table problem? It doesn't seem to fix it.